# Nest multi-speed fan control

Tags: hvac, nest

Based on this site:

https://nest.com/support/article/Learn-more-about-the-Nest-Learning-Thermostat-and-multi-speed-fans

It looks like nest recently added support for multi-speed fan control for some furnaces.

I'm looking to buy a new furnace (mine is old and past its life), but really like using the nest thermostat. It's the first thermostat I've ever used that I actually like. I would like to be able to control as much of the new furnace's features with the nest as possible.

My understanding is that sticking with Nest means I can't use "modulating" or "variable speed" furnaces. However, I think I should be ok with a 2 stage multi speed furnace. 95% efficiency is obviously not as ideal as 98%, but I think I can live with it if it comes with substantial UX benefits.

However, I don't seem (for the life of me) to be able to find any info on what multi-speed furnaces are actually compatible with nest control. In other words, what furnace models use 2 thermostat wires for fan speed control?

Do any of you guys have an info?

Comment: Shopping questions are off-topic; however, if you have specific furnace models in mind but can't find info on whether they'll be compatible with two stage fan control, we can help with that.

Comment: Ok... The website for the Trane XL95 says it has a 4 speed blower motor. Do you know if this is compatible with the nest multispeed fan control?  Will the nest be able to independently set the fan speed?

Comment: Try asking Nest what to look for to determine compatibility. They should have documentation which covers that.

Comment: They do, it's in the link in the OP. It says that it can control multispeed fans if the system has 2 fan wires instead of one. I can't find any info on what furnaces support that, and which ones don't.

Comment: Additionally just because a furnace has a 4-speed blower motor it doesn't mean that 4 speeds are available at the thermostat.  Most furnaces have multi speed blower motors that are installer configurable via jumpers.

Comment: @ScottWisniewski -- that's not going to be in marketing materials.  You'll need to refer to the installer's manual for the furnace.

Answer (score 2):

I am familiar with two basic control schemes for residential units:  (1) Relay logic (old school 24vac on/off), and (2) Communicating (direct digital control via serial communication).

I believe what you seek is any multi-stage furnace that is not exclusively a communicating furnace.  This type of furnace will have a W1 and a W2 for stage 1 and stage 2 heat, and might control the blower speed automatically or it might have multiple discrete fan speed selections labeled G1, G2, etc, which the multi-stage Nest should handle.

I say this based on a brief review of the literature online and I have never actually installed one of the multi-stage Nest thermostats.